# Arithmetic, geometric, harmonic progressions with the same terms, find radius of circle defined by their terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If an A.P (Arithmetic Progression) , a G.P(Geometric Progression)  and a H.P (Harmonic Progression)  have the same first term and same $(2n+1)$th terms and their $n$th terms are $a,b,c$ respectively, the radius of the circle $x^2+y^2+2bx+2ky +ac=0$ is (options are given below)

- (a) $k$
- (b) $|k|$
- (c) $\sqrt{b^2-ac}$
- (d) none of these

My approach is as follows:

First, write the equation of circle in standard form, namely

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 =r^2$$

where $a$,$b$ are centre of the circle and $r$ is its radius.

we have $(x-b)^2+(y-k)^2 = -ac +b^2+k^2........(i)$

Let the first term of the A.P , G.P. & H.P progressions be $x$ (they have same first term in common) and let $z$ be the $(2n+1)$th term of the progressions.

Now, $(2n+1)$th term of A.P. $\Rightarrow  x +(2n)d =z .....(ii)$

$(2n+1)$th term of G.P $\Rightarrow  xr^{2n} =z .....(iii)$

$(2n+1)$th term of H.P. $\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x+2nd} =z.......(iv)$

Now $n$th term of A.P. $\Rightarrow  x +(n-1)d = a .......(v)$ (where $d$ is common difference) ;

$n$th term of G.P.  $\Rightarrow xr^{n-1} = b........(vi) $ (where $r$ is the common ratio)

$n$th term of H.P $\Rightarrow  \frac{1}{x+(n-1)d} =c..........(vii) $

Multiplying $(ii)$ and $(iv)$, we get $z^2 = 1 \Rightarrow z = \pm 1......(viii)$

Also multiplying $(v)$ and $(vii) $ we get $ac = 1.........(ix) $

What should I do next?

Comment: I suggest you find $n$, $d$ and $r$ from system of ($ii$), ($iii$) and ($iv$).

Comment: It's not a very good idea to use the same letter to denote possibly different things...$\,x,$ as variable and as the first term in the progressions, say. Also  the $\,a\,$ as first coordinate of the circle's center and as the $\,n-$th term of the AP...this is going to get pretty messed up.

Comment: @DonAntonio, and also r :)

Comment: An A.P., a G.P., and an H.P. walk into a bar ...

Comment: This question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2218634/602386) has similar arithmetic, geometric, harmonic progressions, namely the same $2n+1$th terms, and specified $n$th terms as $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: With $k$ arbitrary your answer must depend on $k$, and using the equation of the circle, it is easy to formulate a condition for the answer to depend on $k$ alone. It is then a question of checking whether that condition applies.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I suspect you misstated the question and mean for $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be the $n+1$st (middle) terms of the sequences. As you stated the question, a single non-trivial example will quickly exclude answers a), b), and c).

Next, look at a simple example. The sequence (1,1,1), or even the sequence (1), is at once arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic, and therefore $a=b=c=1$ is one possibility. The circle $x^2+y^2+2x+2ky+1=0$ has standard equation $(x+1)^2+(x-k)^2=k^2$, so the radius is $|k|$. For $k=-1$, the radius is neither $\sqrt{b^2-ac}=0$ nor $k$, so the correct answer is either b) or d).

To rule out d) requires a proof, since it could be the case that the radius is often, but not always, $|k|$.

Worth observing is that for a sequence that's harmonic/geometric/arithmetic, the three-term sequence comprising the 1st, $n$-th, and $2n+1$st term is also harmonic/geometric/arithmetic. If $s$ and $t$ are the common first and last terms of the sequences, $a=\displaystyle\frac{s+t}{2}$, $b=\sqrt{st}$, and $c=\displaystyle\frac{2st}{s+t}$. Perhaps you can take it from there.