# What is the proper way of approaching this question about related AP, GP and HP series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If the first and the $(2n+1)$ th terms of an A.P, G.P and H.P are equal and their $n$ th terms are respectively $a,b$ and $c$ then which of the following are true (more than one option may be correct) :

(A) $a=b=c$

(B) $a \geq b\geq c$

(C) $a+c=b$

(D) $ac-b^2=0$

**My Attempt:**

Let first term of all the series be $f$

According to the question,

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}+(2n)D}=f (r)^{2n}= f+(2n)d$$

But, from here I find it difficult to conclude anything about the $n$ th terms. What is the proper way of approaching this question?

P.S:

AP=Arithmetic Progression

GP=Geometric Progression

HP=Harmonic Progression

Answer (score 2):

If the first term is $u$ and the $(2n+1)$st terkm is $v$, then the middle (i.e., $n$th) therm of the AP is their arithmetic mean  $\frac{a+b}2$, that of the GP is their geometric mean $\sqrt{uv}$ (though strictly speaking, it might b $-\sqrt{uv}$ - is there any conditionmissing from the problem statement?), and that of the HP is their harmonic mean $\frac{2}{\frac1u+\frac1v}$. Do you know any relation involving arithmetic/geometric/harmonic means?

Comment: If the first term is $a$ and the $(2n+1)$ th term is $a+2nd$ then their arithmetic mean is $a+nd$ which is the $(n+1)$ th term and not the $n$ th term.